# Haar Cascade OpenCV:

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Im interested to know the details about **Haar classifier xml files** that come with **OpenCV**.

You can find these files at `C:\OpenCV2.2\data\haarcascades\ (haar classifier files)`.

How OpenCV developers made these classifiers?

Any information regarding the number of Positive and Negative Images or Database or anything else will be useful.

Comment: some files contain information but most are without any comments and documentation.

Comment: I want information about frontal face and hand classifiers...Thanks

Comment: These are some links that might help you to read up on the topic. 1. [Haar-like Features.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features)
2. [Training the haar classifier](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html) Hope this helps. :)